# Specific version oracle drivers for BizTalk bindings?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I'm trying to get the oracle bindings for a wcf-custom send port working.
I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.0
```

None of the installs on the oracle site seem to have this version. Any suggestions?

Comment: 32bit? 64bit? design time? runtime?

Comment: I assume 64 bit. It's a driver called by a send port so I have no real idea what it does under the covers. Errors at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a workaround to operate but it's not ideal. I noted the 'add generated items' wizard was able to connect to oracle. The code to do this is in visual studio and is 32 bit code. So I knew the 32 bit code could connect. I created a 32 bit only host and have that much working.

I never got the 64 bit drivers to work but did not try Dan Field's redirect

Comment: Oracle drivers get really finicky if you try to do both 32 and 64 bit on the same machine.  I've seen lots of problems with it.  If this is working you likely do not need the binding redirect, but there's probably an issue wiht your 64 bit installation.

Answer (score 3):

That would be version 11g Release 7 (11.1.7). The 2 comes from .Net 2, I believe.

My notes on installing this for 32 bit hosts are (files downloadable from Oracle):

Get Oracle Developer Tools -  ODTwithODAC1110621.zip

Take defaults and select all items. Will go to C:\app[yourusername]\product\11.1.0 by default.

Then install Patchset for ODT - p6890831_111070_Win32.zip

During the install select the previous installation folder from the earlier step (C:\app[yourusername]\product\11.1.0).
Select the existing Oracle home! It might not be obvious from the screen that it is a drop down – do not select the folder.

That should give you Oracle.Data.Access 2.111.7.0 x86 in the Global Assembly Cache.

There should be 64bit versions available as well.

Answer (score 3):

timobr is right on if you're trying to connect to Oracle 11g.  IF you're trying to connect to 12c, you'll need to update your machine.config bindings to redirect the request for the 11g DLLs to the 12c versions.  See [Sandro Periera's blog](https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/biztalk-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-version2-111-7-0-cultureneutral-publickeytoken89b483f429c47342-or-one-of-its-dependencies-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/) for more details; here's the relevant part to add to machine.config:

```
<runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess"
          publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" />

        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.111.7.0" newVersion="2.112.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Note this has to be done for all applicable .NET verions (including both x86 and x64).

Also note that if you're running on a 64-bit host, you'll need the 64-bit drivers - but the admin console is a 32 bit application, and will not work properly without the 32 bit drivers.  However, installing both on the same machine is a bit challenging...